# Firebase App Distribution - Could not find the APK. Make sure you build first by running ./gradlew assemble[Variant]

Tags: android, firebase-app-distribution

I have recently updated the version of the Firebase Appdistribution Gradle plugin from `1.4.0` to `2.0.1`.

Since then Jenkins started giving the build time error below:

`Execution failed for task app:appDistributionUpload[Variant]. Could not find the APK. Make sure you build first by running ./gradlew assemble[Variant], or set the api Path parameter to point to your APK`

This is my Gradle script on Jenkins:

`... ./gradlew cleanBuildCache :app:testDebugUnitTest :app:appDistributionUpload[Variant] ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with version `1.4.1` Running appDistributionUpload{Variant} no longer automatically rebuilds the app.

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#appdistro_gradle_plugin_v1-4-1

Updating the Gradle script by adding `:app:assemble[Variant]` before `:app:appDistributionUpload[Variant]` solved the issue in my case. Hope it will help others as well.